# challenging to select the api59 through workbench

Tags: workbench

In the workbench, we are unable to select the API version 59. Due to this, the respective version 59 metadata, we are unable to cross-verify the metadata validations in the Workbench, how we can select that api 59?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't select v59.0 at time of writing. There hasn't been a commit in the [workbench github repo](https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench/pulls?q=is%3Apr+is%3Aclosed) to add the necessary WSDL files (and bump the version numbers).

Answer (score 0):

We do not support the [WorkBench tool](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_tools_workbench.htm&release=248&type=5) as mentioned in the release notes. We recommend you use our modern tools like [Code Builder](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/codebuilder/about) or the Salesforce CLI.